# what does '$' mean in OCaml synax?

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml. I saw code like

```
let main_t = Term.(pure main $ address $ port $ pid_file $ log_file $ dbConf)
```

what does '$' symbol mean?

Comment: Not syntax, its a function from `cmdliner`, if you have merlin then you can check the type of it easily.

Comment: In particular, an infix function. http://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner.Term.html#VAL($)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OCaml it is possible to define your own infix and prefix operators. In `cmdliner` library the operator `$` is defined as:

```
  val ( $ ) : ('a -> 'b) t -> 'a t -> 'b t
  (** [f $ v] is a term that evaluates to the result of applying
      the evaluation of [v] to the one of [f]. *)
```

And is actually an infix form of the `apply` function (named `app` in Cmdliner). It is used to accumulate the arguments. Basically, a construct of the form `pure f $a $b $c $d` accepts a function `f` that takes four arguments of type `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, given, that `a` is a value of type `a Term.t`, `b` is a value of type `b Term.t`, etc. In general this is a pattern for building typesafe variadic functions. For more information, about the pattern read the [Applicative Programming with Effects](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf) paper.

Answer (score 4):

There's no predefined meaning in OCaml for `$`. It can be defined as an infix operator; the meaning must come from a library that you're using.

If I had to guess, I'd say that `$` has been defined as a low precedence function application operator. It is used for this in Haskell, and it is often quite handy.

Comment: Yes, it looks like functor application here. But isn't `$` in Haskell typically regular application, with `<$>` being (applicative) functor application?

Comment: No doubt you're right, I forgot what I used to know about Applicative :-)

Answer (score 1):

there is no special meaning of $ in standard ocaml. In your case, this is coming from Term module where specific syntax may be defined. (BTW, which module is it ? - I mean how did you install it)

Comment: It's an infix operator defined by the cmdliner library: http://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner.Term.html#VAL($)